# Grabbing user's messages with command

Tags: discord.py

im writing a very simple discord py bot command, which returns the sentence written by user after saying `$send_back` :

```
@client.command()
async def send_back(ctx,sentence):
    await ctx.send(sentence)
```

i want my bot to return the full sentence, but the problem is that it only returns the first word of the sentence:

> User : $send_back whats upp!

> Bot : whats

what is the best way to solve this problem? i don't want to use `client.wait_for("message")`, i want this to happen with a single message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to **Łukasz Kwieciński**'s answer, you can also use `*args` to catch all arguments without a keyword as a tuple:

```py
@client.command()
async def send_back(ctx, *sentence):
    # sentence = ("whats", "upp!")
    await ctx.send(" ".join(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

For multi-word input use the keyword-only (`*`) argument

```py
@client.command()
async def send_back(ctx, *, sentence):
    await ctx.send(sentence)
```

[Keyword-only arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)